# present perfect with 'since' vs present perfect continuous with 'since'

Tags: grammar

I have painted 2 rooms since tuesday
or
I have been painting 2 rooms since tuesday

I have washed the dishes                                                                                    or
i have washed the dishes since morning
i have been washing the dishes since morning
i was told we can't mention time with present perfect in some cases. which of these sentences are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, "since" refers to the time that has gone by after an event or occasion. Therefore, using "since" places a current statement in a time context. As far as I know, there is no reason to not use it either with completed action or ongoing action.

Both of these are understandable and grammatical in my view:

I have painted two rooms since Tuesday (the painting that I started on Tuesday is completed).

I have been painting two rooms since Tuesday (I started painting two rooms on Tuesday and have been doing that until now; the painting may or may not be completed).

Another way that English speakers define a time span is with "all" --

I have been cleaning the house all morning.

I have been cleaning the house since morning.

I cleaned the house this morning (I finished cleaning).

This is an example of both ongoing AND completed action taking place over a time span referred to with "since."

*Since morning, I have been cleaning, and I made breakfast.*

(After a time considered as 'morning,' I spent time cleaning (and perhaps finished or did not finish) and at some point I prepared breakfast).